# Can't open photos, use store on my htc 8s

Tags: store, photos

Im not being able to view any of my clicked photos on my device or the pre loaded ones either. It just shows blank thumbnails when i open my cameraroll section. When I connect my phone to the pc, it doesnt shows any photos in the internal memory, even the fresh ones I click just for testing.
This started happening just a few days back. Since then even my store is not working. It hasnt been even a month since i bought my phone :(
Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Comment: This is a very awkward behavior. I've never had listen such a thing. Have you tried a reset?

Comment: Do you have a data/wifi connection on your phone?

Comment: I too have the same issue, were you able to resolve your issue!?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your phone has a serious fault, possible with its flash memory (ie. the internal storage of the phone).

I would suggest you either...

1. Bring the phone back to where you bought it, explain the problem and ask for a replacement
2. Contact HTC via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/HTCUSA) or their [website](http://www.htc.com/support/), and try and get a replacement that way.

The GDR2 update should be appearing for all Windows Phone 8 devices, but I don't think that it will fix the issue. It's a far better idea to get the phone replaced.